# Using Wiki API by format JSON can't get the content

Tags: javascript, json, api, mediawiki

I use this code to gathering the information from Wiki:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&rvprop=content&prop=revisions&format=json&titles=apple

And I can get a JSON String like this

```
{
    "query": {
        "normalized": [{
            "from": "apple",
            "to": "Apple"
        }],
        "pages": {
            "18978754": {
                "pageid": 18978754,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Apple",
                "revisions": [{
                    "*": "Something....."
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can eval it to JSON, but the problem is, I can get into the query>pages, after that I can't get deeper, it was Because the Wiki API return me as a String 18978754, but it can't get the value by this:

```
jsonObject.query.pages.18978754
```

Some assumption I need to clarify, I don't know the number 18978754. Do I need to get the number first or I can still get "Something..." within knowing the number.

Comment: Please do not use the generic term `Wiki` to specifically refer to Wikipedia, or the MediaWiki software that it uses.

Comment: just found this, it is experimental, but it rearranges the json so it doesn't start with the number - https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=json  - `&formatversion=2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using array-syntax :

```
jsonObject.query.pages[18978754]
```

Seems to be working, using firebug :

```
>>> data.query.pages[18978754]
Object pageid=18978754 ns=0 title=Apple revisions=[1]
```

And :

```
>>> data.query.pages[18978754].title
"Apple"
```

Note accessing data-object with an array-syntax is also possible for the other properties ; for instance :

```
>>> data['query'].pages[18978754].title
"Apple"
```

That's perfectly valid JS syntax **:-)**

---

**Added after seing the comment / edit**

If you don't know the ids of the pages, you can iterate over the pages, with something like this :

```
for (var pageId in data.query.pages) {
    if (data.query.pages.hasOwnProperty(pageId)) {
        console.log(data.query.pages[pageId].title);
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to be sure the object I'm on has the property, and that it's not coming from any kind of inheritance or anything like that :

> Every object descended from Object
>   inherits the hasOwnProperty method.
>   This method can be used to determine
>   whether an object has the specified
>   property as a direct property of that
>   object; unlike the in operator, this
>   method does not check down the
>   object's prototype chain.

Depending on what's in "`revision`", you might have to do the same on that one too, btw...

Hope this helps better **:-)**

---

**Second edit, after second set of comments :**

Well, going a bit farther (didn't think you meant it literally) :

```
data.query.pages[pageId].revisions
```

is an array (note the `[]` symbols) that seems to be able to contain several objects.

so, you can get the first one of those this way :

```
data.query.pages[pageId].revisions[0]
```

The second one this way :

```
data.query.pages[pageId].revisions[1]
```

*(there is no second one in the example you provided, btw -- so this is in theory ^^ )*

And so on.

To get everyone of those objects, you'd have to do some kind of loop, like this :

```
var num_revisions = data.query.pages[pageId].revisions.length;
var i;
for (i=0 ; i<num_revisions ; i++) {
    console.log(data.query.pages[pageId].revisions[i]);
}
```

And now, inside that loop, you should be able to get the '*' property of the given object :

```
data.query.pages[pageId].revisions[i]['*']
```

So, the final code becomes :

```
for (var pageId in data.query.pages) {
    if (data.query.pages.hasOwnProperty(pageId)) {
        var num_revisions = data.query.pages[pageId].revisions.length;
        var i;
        for (i=0 ; i<num_revisions ; i++) {
            console.log(data.query.pages[pageId].revisions[i]['*']);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this code in firebug, I now get the literral sting you're looking for :

```
Something.....
```

Of course, you could probably just use :

```
for (var pageId in data.query.pages) {
    if (data.query.pages.hasOwnProperty(pageId)) {
        console.log(data.query.pages[pageId].revisions[0]['*']);
    }
}
```

Which will work fine if you always want to deal with only the first element of the `revisions` array.

Just beware : in your example, there was only one revision ; the code I provided should be able to deal with many ; up to you to determine what you want to do with those ;-)

Comment: can I get the "Something....." directly? One more thing, Assume, I don't know the "18978754".... Because this number it depends on different topic from wiki

Comment: Hi, I've edited my answer to show an example of iterating through the pages, when you don't know their ids ; Hope this help :-)

Comment: Can I follow the question? How can I get the  "Something....." value? (Assume I don't know "Something....")
both 
data.query.pages[pageId].revisions.*  and
data.query.pages[pageId].revisions[*]
are not working

Comment: I've edited my answer a second time, to provide a full example (I supposed you'd find out how to get there yourself ; that's why I didn't go farther the first time) ; hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 3):

Late but maybe helpful for someone else.

When you add `&indexpageids` to your request you will get the `pageids`. More information [here](http://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Apple&prop=info&indexpageids&format=jsonfm).

Comment: This really simplifies the problem! It makes navigating the JSON object much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue while creating a php-based parser for the Wiki API - here's how I solved it.

```
$new_result = array_pop($result["query"]["pages"]);

$final_result = $new_result["pageid"];
```

Note: I know this is PHP code in a JS question, but couldn't find exactly the same question/problem in that forum - I'm sure this will be useful for someone.